# Почему не удаляются классы css в методом className в ie 9-11?

Tags: javascript

Есть такая функция:

```
function toggleClass(elem,cls,flag){

  var cls1=elem.className;  

  cls1=cls1.split(' ');

  var i=cls1.indexOf(cls);

  if ( (i >= 0 && flag > 0) || (i <0 && flag < 0)){
      return;
  }

  if(flag < 0){
      cls1.splice(i,1);
  }

  if(flag >= 0){
      cls1.push(cls);
  }

  cls1=cls1.join(' ');

  elem.className=cls1;
}
```

результат ее многократного вызова в ie получается такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в остальных браузерах все OK.
Заранее благодарен за помощь)
функция из которой осуществляется вызов:

```
  function scrollEffect1(){

   var scroll_old = scrollEffect1.scroll_old || -1;   //значение скролла
   var direction;                                          //направление
   var scroll_new = pageYOffset;
   direction = scroll_new - scroll_old;
   var h1 = d.querySelector('h1');
   var ul = d.querySelector('header ul');

   if( scroll_new >=0 && scroll_new < win_size.height) {
           headerScroll(scroll_new, direction); 
           toggleClass(h1, 'header-anim', direction);
           toggleClass(ul, 'header-anim', direction);
   }

   if ( scroll_new >= win_size.height*0.5 && scroll_new <= win_size.height)  { 
       showLeftblock(direction);
       showPhone('scroll',direction);
    }

    if(scroll_new >= win_size.height && scroll_new <= win_size.height*1.5){
        showUp(direction);
    }

   scrollEffect1.scroll_old=scroll_new;
   setPosPoiner();
```

}

Comment: как ты вызываешь функцию?

Comment: из обработчика скролла  при прохождении опред точек вызывается функция: function headerScroll(scroll, flag){
      
      var h1 = d.querySelector('h1');
      var ul = d.querySelector('header ul');
      
      if(scroll < win_size.height * 0.2) {
        toggleClass(h1, 'header-anim', flag);
        toggleClass(ul, 'header-anim', flag);
        }
    
       if(scroll===0)  {
          scroll=1;
      }
      var step = 80-scroll/6;
  
      content[0].style.backgroundSize = +step+'% auto';
  }

Comment: из этой функции вызывается наша проблемная

Comment: если вызвать напрямую из обработчика все точно также

Comment: добавь этот пример в вопрос. Что за flag?  какое значение ты ему присваиваешь?

Comment: как добавить пример? flag это направление скролла(новое значение скрола - старое значение = flag ), т.е. оно либо больше нуля либо меньше

Comment: ты можешь отредактировать свой вопрос с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: отредактировал, причем повторюсь это проблема только IE 9-11 даже LUNASCAPE в режиме IE все отлично

Comment: Только что проверил `toggleClass` в IE11, работает нормально. Хотя я бы изменил третью строку на `cls1 = cls1 ? cls1.split(' ') : [];`, чтобы избавиться от лишнего пробела, но на саму функциональность это не повлияет.

Comment: а вызывали функцию один раз или несколько?

Comment: при медленной прокрутке вручную происходит вызовов 10-20 в каждом направлении, при плавной прокрутке скриптом 2-3 вызова.